# WebView and scale image

Tags: android, webview

I create webview in code. In this webview I show pictures. Now I have two questions. How I can show image in full size, because my pictures has resolution 1381x1829 and I see only part of this picture. And second. As you can see in code I load pictures from assets, but I want to load pictures from sd card. How I can do that?

This is code:

```
    WebView web = new WebView(getContext());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/lj.png");


addView(web);
```

Comment: did u try zooming out like this `webview.setInitialScale([scale])`

Comment: works great, but I wont my picture on full screen, I want fill that screen like ScaleType.fill_XY. This is possible? . And how about loading this photos from sd card? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method `webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true)` will let you implement build in zoom control for non-multitletouch screen

You can load image from anywhere from sdcard to webview using this code.
That is if u want to load multiple image from multiple location.

```
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/Your/Folder";
String imagePath = "file:/"+ base + "/test.jpg";
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html","utf-8");
```

But if u want to load images exist under the same parent folder, this will do the trick

```
String imagePath = "test.jpg";
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///mnt/sdcard/Your/Folder/", html, "text/html","utf-8",null);
```

BE WARN, if u try to load hi-res image like 1600x1840 to webview, webview WILL reduced image res to maintain memory usage, which result in BAD looking image

Comment: Work, but picture has white margins. I want fill webview this image without any margins.

Comment: Pal, that's u'r html problem.
No offence, but I think u should google about that one.

Answer (score 3):

this solution works perfectly for me :

```
webView.setInitialScale(30);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your HTML  :

```
<style type='text/css'>
   img {max-width: 100%;height:initial;} div,p,span,a {max-width: 100%;}
   </style>
```

This will make your images scale to fit the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

For remove default padding - don't forget set style:

```
<html><head></head><body style="padding:0; margin:0;"><img src=""+ gifUrl + ""
width="100%"></body></html>
```